# How can I see my votes on questions only?

Tags: support, questions, badges, voting, electorate-badge

I want to see how many questions I have voted on, and the percentage vs. answer votes. (This is important for the [Electorate badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732).)

Comment: The counter is at the bottom right of the activity tab in your profile.

Comment: Profile -> Activity -> Summary -> Bottom of page. But I'm sure this has been asked before.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41932/can-i-see-my-vote-history

Comment: By the way, I am pretty much sure that comment votes aren't part of the calculation. It is *question_votes / (question_votes + answer_votes)*.

Comment: @duplode You're right, edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see this in the bottom right corner of your [profile summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3803058/acarroz5?tab=summary).

[image]

But there's an even better way to see it if you're going for the Electorate badge: when you *track* it on your profile, you can click on it:

[image]

There's no need to calculate the percentage yourself.